# What C++ library to use to write a cross-platform service/daemon?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, service, daemon, multiplatform

I wonder what library would ease the development of a cross-platform service/daemon ? (C/C++)

I'm targeting: Windows, Linux and OS X.
Requirements: network operations and serial port communication.

Also it would be nice to have a basic sample service application.

Comment: I realize this question is really, really old but I recently developed a related piece of software that doesn't directly answer the question:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/service-manager/  It's not a library but it does deal with the difficulties of writing cross-platform system services.  The source code happens to be written in C++ but that's mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to Qt you might try [qt-service](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice).

Comment: 5 years out and this is still the top answer in a google search. Updated link: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice

Comment: @chadwick.boulay link-rot fixes should really be edits, not comments.

Comment: Is there any other alternative other than `Qt`?

Comment: What about GTK?

Answer (score 6):

A daemon in Linux is really just  a process that runs disconnected from a terminal. In Windows, a service is something that can be controlled using the service management API, but once again is basically just a disconnected process. The disconnection aside, daemons & servers don't have much in common, from task to task. There is no requirement, for example, that they be multi-threaded, be asynchronous or perform network I/O. Given that, it's kind of hard to see what  a cross-platform library would do.

Comment: Linux daemons are expected to be started automatically by the init process (i.e. init or systemd), which requires an init script and some other setup. They should typically also respond appropriately to SIGINT and often to SIGHUP or other catchable signals.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/).  Depending on what you are doing it could have facilities to do a large amount of the work for you with a lot less work than Boost.

An obligatory mention for [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) though I don't personally care for it much.

Comment: ugh, I hate ACE. If anything, boost is much better. both suck for different reasons though. zeroMQ is worth a try maybe. I haven't tried POCO yet, looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) probably has most of what you need in terms of [threading](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) and [networking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) I/O.

You may also find [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) a good alternative. It also has threading and networking libraries and has a much easier to use & understand event-driven programming model using a run loop. Qt's signal/slot system is very easy to use and ideal for a network daemon/service (Boost also includes a [signal/slot](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals.html) system but it is harder to use and does not include an event loop; you have to roll your own using some event library). As a cross-platform library, Qt can handle many of the issues in bridging the Unix (OS X and Linux) vs. Windows mental model for processes, filesystems, etc.

For unit testing, I've been very happy with Google's C++ unit testing library called [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) (though both Boost and Qt also have built-in unit testing systems). It runs on all the platforms you specify. I've done a lot of work with googletest on cross-platform Qt projects and found it quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a big library in the non-boost version of ASIO.  You don't need all boost library but only this little headers-only and very well documented library http://think-async.com/

As examples, a daytime server-client system is implemented in very few lines of code.
Take a look at it.

(remember to look at the non boost-ized version)